# Ember: store not available in Application.initializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have implemented an authentication based on [this](http://log.simplabs.com/post/57702291669/better-authentication-in-ember-js) article

I thus create an `App.Session` object at application initialization:

```
    Ember.Application.initializer({
      name: 'session',

      initialize: function (container, application) {
        App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
          init: function () {
            this._super();
            this.set('authToken', $.cookie('auth_token'));
            this.set('authAccountId', $.cookie('auth_accountId'));
            this.set('authAccountLanguage', $.cookie('auth_accountLanguage'));
          },

          authAccountIdChanged: function () {
            var authAccountId = this.get('authAccountId');
            $.cookie('auth_accountId', authAccountId);

            //Load the actual account record from the server if the authAccountId is set 
            //Used to have for example the full name or other properties of the account
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(authAccountId)) { 
              this.set('authAccount', this.store.find('account', authAccountId));
            }
          }.observes('authAccountId'),
...
```

I have an observer on `authAccountId`; thus each time the `accountId` (the `id` of the logged in user) is changed, I want to retrieve all details of that user (full name, preferences, etc.).

Before Ember data version 1.0.0, I was using:

```
this.set('authAccount', App.Account.find(authAccountId));
```

And this worked. Now I use: `this.set('authAccount', this.store.find('account', authAccountId));`

And I receive the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`. Also in debugger, `this.get('store')` results in undefined. I have the impression that the store is not available in `Application.initializer`. Can somebody help resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `container.lookup('store:main')` this will return the store registered in container:

```
var store = container.lookup('store:main');
this.set('authAccount', store.find('account', authAccountId));
```

Comment: What would you do if `container.lookup('store:main')` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Hmm this is strange `container.lookup('store:main')` should be still available.

Comment: @BenMorganIO FWIW, that problem can probably be solved in that you add `after: 'store'` in the `export default` of the initializer.